# Is it possible to add title to a graph in an R document knited to word?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, knitr

[image]I am using a loop to create several graphs using ggplot2. I've added titles to graphs using the `labs()` or the `ggtitle()` functions on ggplot2.
I wanted to know if there is a way of adding a title in the Rmarkdown document so that when I knit it to Word I get a title like the one that Microsoft Word creates. I want to do this because I have to create several graphs and would rather add the title with code, than manually.
A title like the one in the image above.

Thank you

Comment: Rmarkdown in general supports `title:` as part of the yaml header, and it is translated into all of the outputs (including docx).

Comment: Yes, I used that to set the title of the document but this did not work for graphs titles.

Comment: Okay. It would be very useful if you could provide a minimal reproducible example, one that when rendered into html or pdf generates plot titles, but when rendered into docx does *not* include the title.

Answer (score 2):

There is **not** a way of adding a figure caption in the Rmarkdown document so that when I knit it to Word I get a [figure caption like the one that Microsoft Word creates](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-format-or-delete-captions-in-word-82fa82a4-f0f3-438f-a422-34bb5cef9c81).

You can use

````
```{r fig.cap="My ggplot"}
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + 
  geom_point()
```
````

instead of

````
```{r}
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + 
  geom_point()
```
````

to add a "caption" paragraph after the image block.